# how to run TF2.0 code on a particular GPU

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Hi, I have two GPUs and sometimes I want to run one script on GPU:0 and the other one on GPU:1. the question is how can I execute a python script on a specific GPU, or how to bind script execution to a particular GPU. Looking ahead I'll say what I know about `with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):`

I thought I can solve my issue using  `tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices` but I was wrong. The plan was simple: at the top of the code, I planned to set up the required GPU. And then, as I thought,  the script will run on that GPU which I made visible. But I was wrong - see the code below. In my case when I run the script I got an error:

*TensorFlow device (GPU:0) is being mapped to multiple CUDA devices (1 now, and 0 previously),
which is not supported. This may be the result of providing different GPU configurations
(ConfigProto.gpu_options, for example different visible_device_list) when creating multiple
Sessions in the same process. This is not currently supported, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19083*
__

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def work():
    a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

    for i in range(100000):
        c = tf.matmul(a, b)

def main():
    print(tf.__version__)

    tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(False)
    tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        try:
            print(f'set visible GPU device as {gpus[1]}')
            tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[1], 'GPU')
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(e)

    device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
    print(device_name)

    with tf.device('/device:GPU:1'):
        work()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I believe I'm not the first person who meets with this issue - could somebody share the solution?

Comment: You cannot change GPU configurations once tensorflow has initialized. You can only switch between the GPUs TF reads during initialization using `with tf.device`.

Comment: thx for the answer, but your answer brings more question than the answer:) for instance:

- 1. where is that initialization TF point after which I can't change GPU configuration?

- 2. if ```tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices``` does not change environment configuration why this method exists? 

and at last - the main question still actual: how to run a script on a specific GPU, not part of the code only?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72240094/5290519

Answer (score 1):

as turn it out the casket opened simple - here is what I find out. When you have 2 GPU and call  `tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[1], 'GPU')`  they're only one GPU will be available for your script Device:1 (In my example) .  BUT... **IT IS IMPORTANT** - the name(number) of this device will be Device:0 instead of Device:1 as it can be expected. And here is the reason:  **the system re-enumerates all available for your script GPUs beginning from the scratch** - it means the first name of your device will be started from 0 again, despite your real device that has the name Device:1 -  thus the available in your script device will have name Device:0, not Device:1.

I hope this can help someone like me.